# Error in Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) stand alone Installation

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-desktop

While I want to write an app for Windows 10 IoT on Raspberry Pi 3 B I need to install Visual Studio 2015 Community with Windows SDK on a Windows 10 PC.

I already have a Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 installed and downloaded Windows SDK 10 stand alone but when I click on sdksetup.exe I encounter this error :

> Some Features already installed on this computer are missing from the downloaded setup package.
>
> Download the folowing features before retrying setup on this computer.
>
> - OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit
> - OptionId.WindowsSoftware DevelopmentKit

[image: You can see that in this picture]

I am a bit confused. Why does it need to have packages that it says already installed and the thing is I want these packages to install I don't have them yet!

I will be appreciated if any body can help me and I will send any extra information if needed.

Comment: Sigh, whomever is responsible for writing this installer in the Windows division deserves twenty lashes and should be forced to work together with DevDiv to get this never-ending misery sorted out.  Don't follow any of the cryptic advice, it is nonsense.  Post to the MSDN Forums to try to get a hold of them.  Or consider installing it on another machine and copy the files you need.

Comment: Do you mean it is a long lasting problem?

Comment: No.  It just means that if you have a choice to spend the next two hours of your life between installing the SDK or visiting the dentist to get a root canal done then you should always pick the dentist.  It will hurt less.

Comment: Ran into the same problem after creating a standalone SDK installation. I found a file named UserExperienceManifest.xml in the directory of the installer. Deleting it seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I downloaded Windows SDK 10 stand alone with only Debugging Tools as selected. Deleting UserExperienceManifest.xml did not solve my problem. I resolved the issue by performing following steps.

- Install following installer(.msi) files, located in Installers folder near sdksetup.exe, by double clicking themone bye one.

  1. \Installers\SDK Debuggers-x86_en-us.msi
  2. \Installers\X86 Debuggers And Tools-x86_en-us.msi
  3. \Installers\X64 Debuggers And Tools-x64_en-us.msi
- Confirm and verify whether C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe and C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe are created with all other binaries.
- Now, open QtCreator. Go to Tools | Options | Build & Run | Debugger tab.
- Verify above cdb.exe files paths are listed under Auto-detected section.

Debugging starts working after this.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a bad set of checks in the installer, where you previously have installed an earlier version of the Windows SDK.

None of the solutions I came across worked, but I ended up fixing it.

I used CCleaner to remove bad Registry entries, and went through the registry manually and removed relevant keys that referenced the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits` directory.

After I cleaned up the registry, it still didn't work, so I removed the UserExperienceManifest.xml file, and it ran the installer.

I think the combination of cleaning the registry and deleting that file were both key in getting this installer to work.

Just to be safe, I also ran a repair on my Visual Studio installation.

Hopefully this helps someone else. Been messing with this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just set **All Option**, And download them to local storage,
excepting some option cause triggering error that needs more package.

Only setting method more package is that download from internet on MS. 
but this error occur when downloading fails, like when it is offline.

So, just set **All Option**. And download **Setup**.
Use it to install.